# How to use foreach loop in php for retrieve data from data base to jquery-ui accordion

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, foreach

How to use foreach loop in php for retrieve data from data base to jQuery-ui accordion. I want to user jQuery accordion for fetch data from database. I tried many ways but I can't to do that because of lack of my knowledge. I used jQuery-ui for this one.

This is the code I wrote for this

```
<body>
    <div class="container" style="width:900px;">
   <div id="accordion"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.ajax({ 
   url: "fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   dataType: "json",       
   success: function(data)

   {
  console.log(data);
    $( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    //console.log(data);
    var device_ID;
    var sensor_ID;
} );
   }   
 });

});
</script>
```

This is the PHP part:

```
<?php
//fetch.php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "kapra_iot");
$query = "
 SELECT * FROM `view_sensor`
";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
//$output = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 $sub_data["device_ID"] = $row["device_ID"];
 $sub_data["device_Name"] = $row["device_Name"];
 $sub_data["sensor_ID"] = $row["sensor_ID"];
 $sub_data["sensor_Name"] = $row["sensor_Name"];
 $sub_data["lower_Value"] = $row["lower_Value"];
 $sub_data["mid_Value"] = $row["mid_Value"];
 $sub_data["upper_Value"] = $row["upper_Value"];
 $data[] = $sub_data;
}
foreach($data as $key => &$value)
{
 $output[$value["device_ID"]] = &$value;
}
foreach($data as $key => &$value)
{
 if($value["sensor_ID"] && isset($output[$value["sensor_ID"]]))
 {
  $output[$value["sensor_ID"]]["nodes"][] = &$value;
 }
}
foreach($data as $key => &$value)
{
 if($value["sensor_ID"] && isset($output[$value["sensor_ID"]]))
 {
  unset($data[$key]);
 }
}
echo json_encode($data);
//echo '<pre>';
//print_r($data);
//echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: simply I want to know how to use jquery-ui accordion with mysql and php

Comment: https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: There is a lot of work that needs to be done here. Not sure why you are using POST when GET would work for your script. Please provide a example of the resulting JSON for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd point you to the docs just as Kumar Praveen did. The Accordion will display the different sections titles using the h3 tag and the inner section of each one inside div tags.

Loop trough the result and add it to your accordion div following the syntax described before.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "fetch.php",
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            for (device in data)
            {
                $("#accordion").append("<h3>"+device['device_id']+" " + device['device_Name'] + "</h3>");
                $("#accordion").append("<div><p> Insert here all the relevant data of your device including all the other variables</p></div>");
            }

            $("#accordion").accordion();

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Widget Factory](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/), you can extend accordion to a remote source.

```js
$(function() {
  var testData = [{
    "device_ID": 1001,
    "device_Name": "Device 1",
    "sensor_ID": 597,
    "sensor_Name": "Sensor 1",
    "lower_Value": 0,
    "mid_Value": 50,
    "upper_Value": 100
  }, {
    "device_ID": 1002,
    "device_Name": "Device 2",
    "sensor_ID": 598,
    "sensor_Name": "Sensor 1",
    "lower_Value": 0,
    "mid_Value": 500,
    "upper_Value": 1000
  }, {
    "device_ID": 1003,
    "device_Name": "Device 3",
    "sensor_ID": 599,
    "sensor_Name": "Sensor 1",
    "lower_Value": 0,
    "mid_Value": 0.05,
    "upper_Value": 0.1
  }];

  $.widget("custom.buildList", $.ui.accordion, {
    options: $.extend(this.options, {
      source: "",
      data: []
    }),
    _create: function() {
      console.log("Init");
      this.element.addClass("custom-list");
      var action;
      if (this.options.source == "") {
        action = "html";
      } else if (typeof this.options.source == "string") {
        action = "ajax";
      } else {
        action = "array";
      }
      console.log("Action", action);
      if (action !== "html") {
        if (action === "ajax") {
          this.options.data = this._getData(this.options.source);
        }
        this._makeList(this.element);
      }
      console.log("Return to _create");
      return this._super();
    },
    _getData: function(url) {
      console.log("Getting Data", url);
      $.getJSON(url, function(resp) {
        this.options.data = resp;
      });
    },
    _makeList: function(tObj) {
      console.log("Making List");
      var myData;
      if (this.options.data.length == 0) {
        myData = this.options.source;
      } else {
        myData = this.options.data;
      }
      console.log("List Data", myData);
      $.each(myData, function(i, d) {
        var hd = $("<h3>").html(d.device_Name);
        var bd = $("<div>");
        var ls = $("<ul>").appendTo(bd);
        $.each(d, function(k, v) {
          $("<li>").html(k + ": " + v).appendTo(ls);
        });
        tObj.append(hd, bd);
      });
    }
  });

  $("#accordion").buildList({
    source: testData
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="width:900px;">
  <div id="accordion"></div>
</div>
```

This extension allows a URL or Array to be passed in as a Source option. So if you wanted to use it to get data from a PHP Script, you could do:

```
$("#accordion").buildList({
  source: "fetch.php"
});
```

The extended widget will collect the data from the URL or Array and build the needed HTML before calling on the rest of the widget. I had to test with an array. You will also need to modify `_makeList()` function to meet you various needs.

It is also built to default back to HTML if you so choose. Also you have all the same options as you would with a standard Accordion widget.